# Php get file extension from array value

Tags: php

I'm new php, It's learning process.

I've a html upload form. I'm trying to rename the uploaded file. So Following is php code that get the file extension and after that i add a php  uniqid(); to rename it.

**Get file extension code:**

```
$img = $_FILES['images']['name'];

function getExtension($str)
{
     $i = strrpos($str,".");
     if (!$i) { return ""; } 

     $l = strlen($str) - $i;
     $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
     return $ext;
}

$extension =  getExtension($img);
$id = uniqid();
$newimg = $id.'.'.$extension;
```

Well, this OK for me for only one upload file, **BUT** if I've multiple upload form then how do i get multiple files extension with this function?

**For get the multiple files following is my php code:**

```
$uploaded_files = array();
$upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory    


for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++)
            {
                $number_of_file_fields++;

                if ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != '')
                { //check if file field empty or not
                    $number_of_uploaded_files++;

$uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory .   $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]))
                    {
                        $number_of_moved_files++;
                    }

                }

            }
```

**Html Form**

```
<table width="1020" border="0" cellspacing="7" cellpadding="0">   
<tr>
 <td valign="top" width="250">
     Upload your property picture
 </td>
 <td>
    <div id="file_container">
        <input name="images[]" type="file" class="tr2"  />
        <br />
    </div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="add_file_field();">Add another</a>
 <input type="submit" value="Save & Continue" name="Submit" class="submit" />
 </td>  
</tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function changeFilename($str)
{
     $pathinfo = pathinfo($str);
     return uniqid() . "." . $pathinfo['extension'];
}
$oldarray = array("hello.txt","ytuwe.php");
$newarray = array_map("changeFilename", $oldarray);
var_dump($newarray);
```

Here is a demonstration: http://ideone.com/gPi61D

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Asad. is the $oldarray is $uploaded_files array()?

Comment: @Babu Yes, `$oldarray` is the array with unchanged filenames, whereas `$newarray` has the filenames changed to unique IDs.

Comment: Is this function get all the files from images[] and rename it?

Comment: @Babu I had mixed up the order of arguments to `array_map`. Try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function from PHP to get the file extension ?

```
$extension = pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$id = uniqid();
$newimg = $id.'.'.$extension;
```